# How many solutions are there to $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{2^a}$ when $a\geq 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know there is a result that says $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ has only $\pm 1$ as solutions for $p$ an odd prime. Experimenting with $p=2$ shows that this is no longer the case. I ran a few tests on WolframAlpha, and noticed a pattern that there seem to be $4$ solutions to $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{2^a}$ when $a\geq 3$, and they are $\pm 1$ and $2^{a-1}\pm 1$. This works fine for the first several cases, but I'm wondering how you would actually prove that these are the only 4 solutions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel's_lemma

Comment: The other direction is easy but enlightening.  $(2^{a-1}\pm 1)^2=2^a\pm 2\cdot2^{a-1}+1\equiv 1 \pmod{2^a}$ and it shows the other factor of $2$ comes from the cross term in the square, which is why you don't get any more as $a$ increases.

Comment: How to use Hensel's Lemma to solve this problem? $f'(x) \equiv 0 (\bmod 2)$. So I can't lift the power of $2^a$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, Hensel's Lemma is a bit of overkill here. Anyway, when I teach undergraduate number theory I emphasize the connections to undergraduate algebra.  Here you are trying to find the elements of order $2$ in the finite abelian group $U(2^a) = (\mathbb{Z}/2^a \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, so it would be very helpful to know how this group decomposes as a product of cyclic groups.

This group structure is usually computed around the same time one shows that $U(p^a)$ is cyclic for all odd $p$.  The answer is that for all $a \geq 3$, $U(2^a) \cong Z_2 \times Z_{2^{a-2}}$, i.e., it is isomorphic to the product of a cyclic group of order $2$ and a cyclic group of order $2^{a-2}$.  See e.g. Theorem 1 [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400primitiveroots.pdf) for a proof.

Can you see how to use this result to prove your conjecture?

Comment: I just fixed a small typo in your answer (adding a period).

Comment: Thanks Pete L. Clark. I'm not too familiar with this, but here's what I think I gathered. I want to count all elements of order $2$ in $Z_2\times Z_{2^{a-2}}$? This is the same as the number of elements $(1,b)$ where $b$ has order $2$ in $Z_{2^{a-1}}$? But isn't $b=x^{2^{a-3}}$, where $x$ is the generator of $Z_{2^{a-2}}$ the only such element? Shouldn't I be counting 3 elements of order 2?

Comment: @Joe: close.  You want all the elements of order at most $2$ in the product (of course the only element of order $1$ is the identity).  It turns out that an element $(x,y)$ in a direct product has order at most $2$ iff both $x$ and $y$ have order at most $2$.

Comment: Oops, I was just looking at elements of order $2$, not at most $2$. The 4 elements would be $(1,\pm 1)$ and $(1, \pm x^{2^{a-3}})$, so there are exactly 4 elements of order at most 2 in $U(2^a)$. Thanks, I really like this view of the problem.

Comment: @Joe: Not quite. When we switched to the notation $\mathbf{Z}_2\times\mathbf{Z}_{2^{a-2}}$ the group operation became componentwise *addition*. So the four elements of order at most 2 are $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,2^{a-3})$ and $(1,2^{a-3})$. The isomorphism maps these back to the multiplicative group. You are correct in that in a cyclic group of even order there is only a single element of order two. But here the group is a direct sum/product of two cyclic subgroups, and you have the option to vary **both** components.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $ $ It's easy: $\, d\ |\ x\!-\!1,\,x\!+\!1\, \Rightarrow\, d\ |\ x\!+\!1\!-\!(x\!-\!1) = 2.\,$ Thus if $\, 2^{a}\ |\ (x\!-\!1)(x\!+\!1)\:$ there are only a few ways to distribute the factors of $\,2\,$ such that $\,\gcd(x\!-\!1,x\!+\!1)\,$ is at most $\,2.$

Comment: Thanks Bill Dubuque, that's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

More generally,  it's a standard result in number theory that if $a\equiv 1\pmod8$, then $$x^2\equiv a\pmod {2^\alpha}$$ has $2^2=4$ solutions for $\alpha \ge3$.

See Vinogradov, *Elements of Number Theory*,  Dover, p.$94$ for an even more general statement.