# Number of solutions to the congruence $x^2\equiv 121\pmod {1800}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I'm trying to find the number of solutions to this congruence:
 $$x^2\equiv 121\pmod {1800}$$

I thought about writing it as a system of congruences. As $1800=3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 2^3$, we get:

$x^2\equiv 121\pmod {5^2} \;,\; x^2\equiv 121\pmod {3^2} \;,\; x^2\equiv 121\pmod {2^3}$

$\Downarrow$

$ x^2\equiv 21\pmod {5^2} \;,\; x^2\equiv 4\pmod {3^2} \;,\; x^2\equiv 1\pmod {2^3} $

Now I'm pretty stuck with how to solve each of the above quadratic congruences, is there a fast way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

We need $\left(\dfrac x{11}\right)^2\equiv1\pmod{3^2,5^2,2^3}$

Now we can prove $y^2\equiv1\pmod{p^n}$ has exactly two solutions for prime $p\ge3$ and integer $n\ge1$

Finally we can apply [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) to find the number of in-congruent solutions to be $$4\cdot2^2$$

**See also**: [Number of solutions of $x^2=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104961/number-of-solutions-of-x2-1-in-mathbbz-n-mathbbz)

Comment: But for example the congruence $x^2\equiv 1\pmod {2^3}$ has 4 solutions: $1,3,5,7$

Comment: @user401516, Thanks, please follow the link in my post

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand why what you stated is correct. Also, how can I find the number of solutions when $p=2$?

Comment: @user401516, Have you followed the link

Comment: I haven't learned the theorem used there, also I'm pretty sure there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not a fast way.  To solve $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p^n}$ we first solve $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p}$ and then use Hensel's Lemma to "lift" the solution to $\pmod{p^2}$ and then $\pmod{p^3}$, etc.  Sometimes the solutions lift uniquely, sometimes not.

In the case of your problem, there are two solutions modulo $5$ which lift uniquely to two solutions modulo $25$.  The exact same thing happens modulo $9$.
There is one solution modulo $2.$  It lifts to two solutions modulo $4.$  Each of these in turn lifts to two solutions modulo $8$, for a total of 4 solutions modulo $8.$

So in the end, there are $2\times 2\times 4 = 16$ solutions modulo $1800.$

Comment: I should add that a "fast" square root algorithm for non-prime moduli would be an earth-shattering invention.  Half of all cryptosystems would be compromised.