# Number of solutions of $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^rq}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to show that the number of solutions of

$$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^rq}, (2^rq) \in \mathbb{N}$$

is $2^{s+t}$ where $s$ = #distinct prime divisors of $q$ and $t$ = 0,1,2 according as $r\le1$, $r=2$, $r\ge3$.

So far I've been able to prove show this for: $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^r}$

I'm having trouble seeing what happens taken mod ($2^r$ **q**) Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you can just apply chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: I was thinking chinese remainder theorem a while back in my thought process..but don't know how this would allow me to determine the number of distinct solution?

Comment: The solutions modulo $2^rq$ correspond to tuples of solutions, one for each prime divisor $q_i$ of $2^rq,$ modulo $q_i^{r_i}$ where $q_i^{r_i}||2^rq.$

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I just don't see this

Comment: @MargretButton, I'm sorry I thought q was prime.

Comment: I still think we may be able to apply the CRT, but I'm struggling with it.

Comment: You can Apply CRT with use of the following results: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55223/how-many-solutions-are-there-to-x2-equiv-1-pmod2a-when-a-geq-3, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/solving-x2-equiv-1-pmodp-ell

Comment: @JavaMan yes, I've proved both of those. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must assume $q$ is odd (the statement certainly isn't true if $q$ is a power of $2$).
Note that if $m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_k$ are relatively prime, $x$ is a solution of $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod m_1 m_2 \ldots m_k$ iff $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod m_1$, $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod m_2,\ \ldots x^2 \equiv 1 \mod m_k$.  If $S_j = \{x \in {\mathbb Z}_{m_j}: x^2 \equiv 1 \mod m_j\}$, then
$x$ is a solution of $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod m_1 \ldots m_j$ iff $x \in S_j \mod m_j$ for each $j$.  By CRT the number of such solutions in ${\mathbb Z}_{m_1 \ldots m_k}$ is 
$|S_1| |S_2| \ldots |S_k|$: each one corresponds to choosing one member $x_1$ of $S_1$, one member $x_2$ of $S_2$, etc, and then taking $x$ so $x \equiv x_1 \mod m_1$, $x \equiv x_2 \mod m_2$, etc.  So you just have to see how many solutions there are mod $2^r$ (which you have already done) and mod $p^m$ if $p$ is an odd prime.  For the latter, 
note that $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)$, and $x-1$ and $x+1$ can't both be divisible by $p$.

Comment: Much appreciated!